# F9 key allows PDFTexify/how do I bind other F key to PDFLaTex?

Tags: pdftex, winedt

In WinEdt 9,
F9 key allows PDFTexify. How do I bind other F key,say F10, to PDFLaTex OR PDFTex? I have some .tex files in PDFTeX and not PDFLaTeX and I need a hot key F10 for them. I will then modify OPTIONS Executions modes by hand as appropriate.

**EDIT**
I've got this:

```
ITEM="PDFLaTeX"
  CAPTION="PDF&LaTeX"
  IMAGE="TeXPDFLaTeX"
  SAVE_INPUT=1
  MACRO="Exe('%b\Exec\TeX\PDFLaTeX.edt');"
  SHORTCUT="122::F11"
  REQ_FILTER=:"%!M=TeX"|"%!M=TeX:STY"|"%!M=TeX:AUX"
ITEM="PDFTeX"
```

NOW it is FINE: works well

Comment: Are you sure that you are using winedt? Imho it never binded F-keys to executables by default? In any case: you can add shortcuts to MainMenu.ini through the option interface. But check first if F11 isn't already in use.

Comment: Yes. WinEdt 9. Cannot find how to add F11 there. Can you write some code here?

Comment: In winedt 8.1 it does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This here from winedt 10. I think in winedt 9 it was similar, but I may have forgotten some differences.

In the option interface click on main menu to open the mainmenu.ini

[image]

Search for the pdflatex entry

```
ITEM="PDFLaTeX"
      CAPTION="PDF&LaTeX"
      IMAGE="TeXPDFLaTeX"
      SAVE_INPUT=1
      MACRO="Exe('%b\Exec\TeX\PDFLaTeX.edt');"
```

and add

```
  SHORTCUT="122::F11"
```

Then load the ini by clicking on the left most icon in the Options interface bar. `122::F11` is the code for F11 on my system. You can check it (and add code for other keys) by using the small keyboard icon in the Options interface bar.