# Winedt 9 exits without asking about saving or discarding changes to a modified file

Tags: pdftex, winedt

After pressing the function key F9 and displaying pdf file,
Winedt 9 exits without **asking** about saving or discarding changes to a modified file. It always did ask about it, but after changing according [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/494490/f9-key-allows-pdftexify-how-do-i-bind-other-f-key-to-pdflatex) (solved) question, it now exits and saves without confirmation. WHY? HOW do I restore asking?

**IN Main Menu I have this:**

```
MENU="&Accessories"
CAPTION="&Accessories"
ITEM="Compile"
CAPTION="&Compile"
CONFIG_FILTER="Default"
IMAGE="Compile"
SAVE_INPUT=1
MACRO="Exe('%b\Exec\Compile.edt');"
SHORTCUT="120::F9"
REQ_FILTER=`"%!M=HTML:HHC"*%P\%N.hhp?"%F=%P\%N.hhp"?"%!M=XWE"?"%!M=TeX"?`+
           `"%!M=MetaPost"?"%!M=MetaFont"?"%!M=NSIS"`+
           `|"%!M=TeX:STY"|"%!M=TeX:AUX"|"%!M=MetaPost:AUX"|"%!M=NSIS:NSH"`
ITEM="Compile_Selected"
CAPTION="Compile &Selected"
CONFIG_FILTER="Default"
IMAGE="CompileSel"
```

Comment: @KJO Sorry, I do not follow what are the numbers 120 and 012 here. Please note that I'm a beginner to WinEdt.

Comment: @KJO Please see my **EDIT**.

Comment: @KJO What I'm claiming is that after modification and pressing F9, WinEdt displays pdf and after closing this pdf, the modified file IS saved...